# dispatch action is not triggering reducer, despite using connect and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an `Icon` in `PostItem.jsx` , I have added `onClick` to it, `onClicking` the Icon it should dispatch an action of `type: LIKE_POST` ,

Well If i `console.log()` inside my dispatch action, the code is working fine , but `reducer.js` is recognizing this action type and I can’t see any action trigger on the console (using `redux logger`).

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-wescoff-vjpf3)

**Click on the Posts Icon on the sidebar and it will render list of post. First Button is like button, second is dislike from Bottom Left**

**Here is my snippet**

```
//PostItem.jsx

const handleLike = (index) => {
console.log(“Inside Like”);
likePost(index);
};

const PostItem = ({ index, key, style, post }) => {
return (

{console.log(“PostItem Rendering”)}
/*Some Extra Code*/}
  <Card.Content extra>
    <Icon
      circular
      onClick={() => handleLike(index)}
      link
      name="heart"
      className="mr-1 fs-icon-md"
      color="teal"
    ></Icon>
    <Icon
      circular
      onClick={() => handleDislike(index)}
      link
      name="heartbeat"
      className="mr-1 fs-icon-md"
    />
    <Icon circular link name="delete" className="mr-1  fs-icon-md" />
    <Icon circular link name="upload" className="fs-icon-md" />
  </Card.Content>
</Card>

);
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
likePost: (index) => dispatch(likePost(index)),
dislikePost: (index) => dispatch(dislikePost(index))
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostItem);
```

postAction.js

**Here is my postActions.js**

```
// Action Creator

export const likePost = (postIndex) => {
  console.log('Indise Like Action');
  return {
    type: postTypes.LIKE_POST,
    payload: postIndex,
  };
};
```

Here is my postReducerr.js

```
//postRedcuer.js
const INITIAL_STATE = {

  posts: [],

  createdPost: null,

  loading: true,

  error: null,

  likedAndDisLikedPost: null,

};

export const postReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

  // Some Extra Cases removed

    case postTypes.LIKE_POST:

      return {

        ...state,

        likedAndDisLikedPost: {

          ...state.likedAndDisLikedPost,

          [action.payload]: { like: true, dislike: false },

        },

      };

    case postTypes.DISLIKE_POST:

      return {

        ...state,

        likedAndDisLikedPost: {

          ...state.likedAndDisLikedPost,

          [action.payload]: { like: false, dislike: true },

        },

      };

    default:

      return state;

  }

};

export default postReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it  I forgot to add `likePost` and `dislikePost` in the Component  as `props`